# Assembly 'XXX' which has a higher version than referenced assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

At the moment I code in an old solution for a customer. At first I want to migrate the system to VS2017.
I solved all problems but one:

> Error  CS1705  Assembly 'Crm.Library' with identity 'Crm.Library, Version=3.2.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Mvc' with identity 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'  Crm.Web C:\Source\src\Crm.Web\CrmApplication.cs 158 Active

So I tried a lot of things like adding this to `web.config`:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Also tried to set the specific version in the config to 'false'

[image: Screen of config]

The problem is still the same..

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: the problem is: to migrate you need to upgrade Crm.Library, which is what it is telling you.

Comment: Is that DLL inside your own project? Or is it in GAC? Check there is the versions match

Answer (score 0):

Your `Crm.Library` assembly, which I'm assuming is probably a class library in your solution, is referencing MVC5, while the project(s) you're including it in are referencing MVC4. You can't mix and match like that. Either `Crm.Library` needs to reference MVC4 like the rest of the projects, or you need to upgrade them all to MVC5.